# Querying Dynamics CRM using Simple.Odata.Client query (Microservice - Web Api net core 2.2)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, dynamics-crm-2016, simple.odata.client

I am doing CRUD operations to Dynamics CRM with the help of Simple.OData.Client in Microservice which is built on asp net core.

Problem is when I run couple of Batch or POST/Patch operations it takes time from 50ms to 17 secs in load testing (50 users, 5 mins, approx. request count is 1000, step pattern, warm up duration 1 min).

I have tried everything like making it InsertEntryAsync(false), UpdateEntryAsync(false), using Key instead if Filter (wherever applicable), adding couple of individual calls to ODataBatch.

Can anyone suggest me what else I can try to bring down the time from 17 secs to couple of mili seconds?

Please let me know if further information is required.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried Visual Studio Profile tool to identify which call stack is causing the most time?

Comment: Yes, hence i am posting here that specific scenario.